# How to order by datediff in WP loop?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I have a custom post type for events with a custom field named event_start_date, and I want to sort the archive loop according to the nearest event_start_date.
In other words, the event with the nearest event_start_date to today should be displayed first.

The SQL query for this would be `ORDER BY DATEDIFF(event_start_date, NOW()) ASC`. But I don't really know how to get this to work in wordpress.

I'm a completely new WP developer, and I've already tried playing around with the args for WP_Query. It only allows me to order by event_start_date which sorts the events as earliest date first, which is not the same as nearest date first.

So is it possible to order a custom field of type DATE according to the difference in date/time from today? If it is how can I do it?

Comment: You can't do it with WP_Query arguments, but there are filters that let you modify the SQL directly, like [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby)

Comment: Thanks @Milo that looks like what I want. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by define `DATEDIFF()` in `SELECT` For example:

```
SELECT RECID, DATEDIFF(t1.qr_enddate, NOW()) AS diffORD 
FROM `mytablw` t1 
ORDER BY diffORD ASC;
```

This should work but in your case I strongly recommend to use wordpress default [Filter API posts orderby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). This filter is applied before a post-retrieving SQL statement is executed. Use it to make custom modifications to the orderby.